# Wire a 30A/15A/30A fuse box to a 4 wire 120V/240V oven

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker, oven

This is for a Canadian Oven being installed in Canada.

Used oven came with this box.

The manual is not available.

The incoming line from both oven and junction are Red/White/Black/Ground.

I understand that the 120V needs the neutral to balance it for the clock/timer but am unsure how.

[image: the included fuse box]

[image: under fuse]

[image: Oven name plate]
[image: oven interior]

[image: Control board]

Control board.
To the left of the white connector it reads 120V

[image: light switch]

Light switch. 
asr 2178-179 
203863-1020
10A1/2HP 120VAC

[image: Broil/Bake selector]

Broil/Bake selector.

[image: Tempature]

Tempature dial.

[image: back panel]

Interior back.

I am not against using a volt meter but not sure what I would be testing with it.

Comment: Should the 15amp fuse be wired to the oven and the block then carry on to supply? 

I have misgivings about conecting that way because I think it is incorect to tie the neutral to the live. 

Also there is no supplied wire for this, not just because its a used oven but because the red 30amp has 2 push conectors to the 15amps 1.

Comment: The white interconnecting wire may have nothing to do with neutral, it may be that color because that's the piece of scrap wire they had laying around when they built it.

Comment: Possible, but it still needs the 15amp in line with the clock/timer somehow.

Comment: Can you post photos of what the oven provides for wiring?

Comment: Honestly this whole thing seems gypsy.  I'd go to the oven proper and see what it requires, you need to provide your circuit protection in the service panel rather than at an intermediate point like this.   The clock/timer does not need separate circuit protection.  What is the make and model of the oven?

Comment: http://imgur.com/ZJIpc5N                   
http://imgur.com/KpIyafF The oven is a kenmore built by either Kelvinator or frigidaire.  I have seen several similar frigidaire models and can verify that some use boxes like this, I have also seen online accounts of jennair models with the same type extrenal fuse box.  The clock/timers function at 120 as the name plat sugests.  There are no other fuses as can be seen.

Comment: I do agree with Harper , I have not seen a 240v oven with a fuse setup like described. In the U.S. It would be a code violation to have a red hot leg connected to another with a white neutral wire. Red and black are the 2 hot legs , white is the neutral and green is the equipment ground usualy connected to the frame. Not sure how things are done up North a clock and timer would draw much less than 1 amp.

Comment: This is NOT the schematic for the above model. It is for a nearly identical looking model branded frigidaire I found on a classifieds page.  The seller was kind enough to make these scans, I do not have the model number. http://m.imgur.com/aSEuQjp. The notanle difference being the additional wire. http://m.imgur.com/c6Rpord. I am posting them here in the hopes they will help.

Comment: Just a quick search for manuals yielded this: http://www.manualslib.com/products/Kenmore-C970-3357507.html You should be able to find something for your model out there.

Comment: The C970 portion of a kenmore model number is a maker mark, in this case kelvinator or frigidaire, the secondary part is the appliance number.  I have tried to find a similar model to inspect the manual but most (all) I have found show the American wiring and do not include the fuse box. The previously posted Wiring diagram is the closest I have come. Contacting Sears directly I was told the Canadian manual is on back order 30-60 days and that if they can not get it in that time they will refund me, sounds like a short term loan to Sears.

Comment: I tried to take a closer look to see if I could trace the 120V visually, I now understand that I don't understand much.  Why would the black line be splice while the red line just receives an extra line? Is this in some way functionaly different? Its not a dpave issue as the black point only has 2 wires to the red and whites 3, that is one main 12awg headed to the plug and 14awg for the oven internals.  http://imgur.com/YZavd5P I know this has nothing to do with the original question, thats why I didn't edit it in.

Comment: Where does the other end (i.e. the end not connected to the 15A fuse) of the white wire in the fusebox go?

Comment: It is conected to the under side of the 30amp fuse with a slide/clip on.  http://imgur.com/rAFeX0Z

Comment: The incoming 120v black is spliced between the control board and tempature dial   The incoming 120v Red is double ring nut with one line to the control board and the other to a double crimp at the element selector (bake/broil) the second crimp carries red to the light switch. The 0v white connects to the control board near the black, the second line disapears into the back of the oven.  I will open the back of the oven and look.  The orange line must be a timer switch. The blue yellow and brown lines connect to the ellements.

Comment: Surprisingly the brown line that are not conected to the temp dial but rather the element selector are for the thermostat.  White it the light bulb balance.  Blue for broil and yellow for bake.

Comment: Stop me if you've heard this one.The most counterintuitive thing to me is that the 15amp is conected to the 30amp red live via push connector. I probably would have wired the 15amp in line with the neutral, reasoning being it is the second half of the 120V bridge. The box design means this must be wrong.  I am left thinking I am missing at least 1 wire (between 15amp and ???)or the 15amp is pointless in this box. The neutral to 15amp also doesnt seem correct because -a. That seems like a hazard -b. It requires parts it didn't come with. -Alternate b. It leaves the neutral not conected at all.

Comment: I found a thread with a Canadian that has a 3 breaker junction box that seems equivalent to the not this model schematic.  Trying to find if there was a code change that negated use of these boxes. http://www.doityourself.com/forum/electrical-ac-dc/406717-wall-oven-wiring-quick-question.html#b

Comment: Decided to bite the bullet and conected it via the standard 4 wire conection, its working fine.   I can only surmise that the fuse box may he from an earlier model (with a seperate control power line) or is a relic of pre 2012 Canadian electrical code. The bothersome part is code normaly defaults to manufacturer instructions and with out them this is all I can do. If you don't hear from me assume I died in a fire and don't follow my lead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fuse box appears to be superfluous -- standard 4-wire 120/240VAC ovens do not need this sort of rigging.  It appears that some antiquated built-in ovens brought their control circuit hot out separately from the oven element hots, hence the fuse box.

Comment: If your oven has 5 wire hookup (White,black,neutral,ground and 1 more line), you may need a fuse box like this.  It also seems to be a Canadian specific issue as all found example were Canadian.

Answer (score 0):

Are the pictures ones for your oven? If so it's a bit confusing that the oven control panel wiring is shown intact and the fuse box picture doesn't show this wire coming in. I assume the fuse box was disconnected from the oven for some reason? The schematic of a similar oven looks appropriate with red/black/white/green coming into the fuse block box but this schematic uses a Yellow for control. The oven control panel pictured is taking off one leg of the 220V power for use as the 120V control power. I would ignore connecting the 15A fuse and connect the red and black to the 30A fuses. White power and white from oven control to the fuse box connection block center terminal and the red and black power to the connection block red and black going to the fuses.

Comment: All images are indeed the oven in question.  It was bought used and disconected. I have hesitations about not wiring the 15a for fear of damaging the electronics.